# Exact inference in an approximate model as opposed to approximate inference in an exact model?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, bounds, approximate-inference

I remember hearing a while ago that it was more rigorous to perform approximate inference in an exact model as opposed to exact inference in an approximate model. I can’t now remember the reasoning behind why that is, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It's always better to get an approximate answer to the right question than an exact answer to the wrong question?

Comment: I guess it depends how wrong vs how approximate. You can derive bounds for both.